# Viewing hover info for overlapping scatter points in Plotly R

Tags: r, plotly

I was surpised I was not able to google this solution, so I thought i'd put up a post. Surely others have the same issue...

The issue I have is that when two or more scatter points overlap (i.e. same x and y), the hover information only shows the info of the top point.

Example:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=1:6, x=c(5:9, 7), y=c(1:5, 3)+10, info=paste('Hover information: ',c(LETTERS[c(1:6)])))
df                 

plot_ly(df) %>% 
  add_trace(x = ~x, 
            y = ~y, 
            type = 'scatter', 
            mode = 'markers', 
            marker = list(color   = 1:6, 
                          symbol  = 1:6, 
                          size    = 25),
            hoverinfo = "text",
            text = df$info)
```

It is possible to make BOTH hoverinfo for the middle point to show up? Possibly as:

```
Hover information: C
Hover information: F
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use add_markers() and jitter, e.g:

```
plot_ly(df) %>% 
  add_markers(x = ~jitter(x, 1), 
              y = ~jitter(y, 1), 
              type = 'scatter', 
              mode = 'markers', 
              marker = list(color   = 1:6, 
                            symbol  = 1:6, 
                            size    = 25),
              hoverinfo = "text",
              text =  ~info)
```

But to get multiple information as you designed, maybe you need to modify your dataframe (but you will lose the colour code):

```
df$info <- as.character(df$info)

df$combined_info[1] <- df$info[1]

for(i in 2:nrow(df)){
  df$combined_info[i] <- df$info[i]

  for(j in 2:i-1){
    if((df$x[j] == df$x[i]) && (df$y[j] == df$y[i])){
      df$combined_info[i] <- paste0(df$combined_info[j], "<br>",
                                    df$info[i])
    }
  }
}
```

And then you can use the original plotly code, while changing the "text" argument:

```
plot_ly(df) %>% 
  add_trace(x = ~x, 
    ...
    text =  ~combined_info)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! Applying jitter is not possible for my use, but you can't know that! Your second option is a good way forward! Thanks a lot!